# QuantLib 1.17 C++ does not contain some YieldTermStructure classes while QuantLib-Swig contains

Tags: programming, quantlib

I want to port some QuantLib-Swig dependent code written in Python to C++ with QuanLib-1.17. However some YieldTermStructure classes (PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount, PiecewiseLinearZero and PiecewiseCubicZero) are not present in QuantLib-1.17.

I found some [yield curve examples](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/test-suite/piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp) that seems to cover those classes' functionalities. However, I want to know can't I find the equivalent of these classes in QuantLib-1.17 C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why there are no specific versions of those classes by discussing with the developer of QuantLib. He stated that

> those classes are instances of a single PiecewiseYieldCurve class
>   template in C++, but need to be exported as separate classes to Python
>   where there are no templates.

I implemented a function template `calculateCurve` and also implemented a main function to show calls to `calculateCurve`:

```
template<class T, class I, template<class C> class B>
ext::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure>
calculateCurve(Date &settlementDate,
               std::vector<ext::shared_ptr<RateHelper>> rateHelpers,
               DayCounter dayCounter,
               const I &interpolator = I())
{
    auto termStructure = ext::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure>(new PiecewiseYieldCurve<T, I, B>(settlementDate,
                                                                                              rateHelpers,
                                                                                              dayCounter,
                                                                                              interpolator));
    return termStructure;
}



int main()
{
    ext::shared_ptr<Quote> rate(new SimpleQuote(0.0019121));
    ext::shared_ptr<RateHelper> rateHelper(new DepositRateHelper(
            Handle<Quote>(rate),
            Period(0, Days),
            2,
            TARGET(),
            Following,
            true,
            ActualActual()
    ));
    std::vector<ext::shared_ptr<RateHelper>> rateHelpers{rateHelper};

    Date settlementDate = Date(01, January, 2017);
    DayCounter dayCounter = Actual360();

    // PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount
    auto result = calculateCurve<Discount, LogCubic, IterativeBootstrap>(
            settlementDate,
            rateHelpers,
            dayCounter,
            LogCubic(CubicInterpolation::Spline));

    // PiecewiseCubicZero
    result = calculateCurve<ZeroYield, Cubic, IterativeBootstrap>(
            settlementDate,
            rateHelpers,
            dayCounter,
            Cubic(CubicInterpolation::Spline));

    // PiecewiseLinearZero
    result = calculateCurve<ZeroYield, Linear, IterativeBootstrap>(
            settlementDate,
            rateHelpers,
            dayCounter);

    return 0;
}
```